# cannot implicitly convert from double?[] to double[]

Tags: c#, linq, casting, nullable

I'm trying to plot a chart by querying a table for the data, and the table columns are nullable. The query runs ok, but passing the query array back to the chart array raises an error `"cannot implicitly convert from double?[]` to double[]". I've searched the net without success. Any suggestions please?

```
//code in the windows form
 private void cmdCHART_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nmCHART.clsCHART oCHART = new nmCHART.clsCHART();

            double[] Y = new double[21];
            Y = oCHART.GET_Y_SERIES("CONDOR"); //can't cast double?[] to double[]
        }

//get data
public double?[] GET_Y_SERIES(string GREEK)
        {

            var qryY = (from P in Globals.DATA.PAYOFF_EAVs
                        where P.GREEK == GREEK
                        orderby P.DP_NO
                        select P.DATA).ToArray();

            return qryY;
        }
```

Comment: try putting `Y = (double[])oCHART.GET_Y_SERIES("CONDOR");`

Comment: thanks but it didn't work - compiler says cast is redundant and I still get the error

Comment: What's the confusion? An array of `double?` is not an array of `double`...

Comment: no confusion, just trying to get the code to work and get the data. Is the cast not possible?

Comment: @Zeus - There is confusion as you're asking this question. You're effectively trying to cast `Foo[]` to `Bar[]` when you're casting from `double?[]` to `double[]`. They are different types.

Comment: Why dont you make Y a nullable type? Like this: `double?[] Y = new double?[21];`

Comment: ok, but you can cast decimal to double etc so is it not possible to cast from double?[] to double[]. How else would you get the data from the query?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial about C# nullable types. Pretty much every answer that you have downvoted has been correct.

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything, I'm digesting all the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cast` to convert it to double.

```
Y =   oCHART.GET_Y_SERIES("CONDOR").Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

To avoid the `null` values in the conversion use this.

```
Y =   oCHART.GET_Y_SERIES("CONDOR").Where(d=>d.HasValue).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

Working [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5g40oc)

Comment: this would throw an exception if one if the values is null

Comment: I'll try your solution as well, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are working with a nullable type, you need to get the actual 'value' from it. You can do something like this:

```
var data = new List<double>();
foreach (var datum in oCHART.GET_Y_SERIES("CONDOR"))
{
    if (datum.HasValue)
    {
       data.Add(datum.Value);
    }
}

var y = data.ToArray();
```